# How can i use preg_replace for show video on youtube

Tags: php, iframe, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to show a video on Youtube that i use preg_replace for replace any `**link**` to `<iframe src="link"></iframe>` when see code in *Inspect Element* on Firefox html code is correct but it doesn't work, and i don't know why. And my code is below. Thanks for helps or suggest.

```
$string = "This is video on youtube **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKTBUmrwYDs**";
$string = preg_replace("/\*\*([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])\*\*/i",'<iframe width="420" height="315" src="$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',$string);
echo $string;
```

And this doesn't work too.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\*\*([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])\*\*/i","<object width=\"420\" height=\"315\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"$1?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"$1?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"420\" height=\"315\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></embed></object>",$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$string = "This is video on youtube **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKTBUmrwYDs**";

preg_match( '#http(s?)://(((www\.)?youtube\.com)|(youtu\.be))/((watch.*(\?|\&)v=([^&]+))|((embed/)?([a-z0-9\-_]+))|)#i' , $string , $matches );

$youtube_id = array_pop( $matches );

$iframe_tag = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="'.$youtube_id.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```